# How can I control the display of a double matrix in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, matrix, format, display

How can I change the format to **NOT** display a matrix like this:

```
 1.0e+003 *

3.1251         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0
     0    3.1251         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0
     0         0    3.1251         0         0         0         0         0         0         0
     0         0         0    3.1251         0         0         0         0         0         0
     0         0         0         0    3.1251         0         0         0         0         0
     0         0         0         0         0    3.1251         0         0         0         0
     0         0         0         0         0         0    3.1251         0         0         0
     0         0         0         0         0         0         0    3.1251         0         0
     0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0    3.1251         0
     0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0    3.1251
```

but instead to include the `1.0e+003` into every double so that the matrix looks like `3125` along the diagonal?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can get the output you want if you [change the format](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/format.html) to `shortG` (based on [Example 5](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/format.html#btixwz8-1_2) of the documentation):

```
>> format shortG
>> 3125.1234.*eye(5)   %# Display a sample matrix similar to yours

ans =

       3125.1            0            0            0            0
            0       3125.1            0            0            0
            0            0       3125.1            0            0
            0            0            0       3125.1            0
            0            0            0            0       3125.1
```